# Better use of redundant subquery in sql- case

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a question for SQL- Statements: Is it possible to "define a sub query" for multiple use in case. It sounds a bit confusing but with the following example I think it is clear what I have in mind:

```
select 
 Column1,
 Column2,
 Case
    WHEN <BigSubquery> > 0 THEN <BigSubquery>
    ELSE 0
 END
from ...
```

How can I do this, or what can I use. I have such a query which works wonderful, but it is a huge code and not useable for maintenance.

Comment: You can probably rewrite this as a more sensible join.  However, without seeing the rest of the query, it is imprudent to give advice.  For instance, are the two subqueries correlated or not?

Comment: am comparing values from two different tables: From one table I have to calculate a e.g. sum val1 and I have to compere the sum with a value from the second table val2. Depending on the condition would it be like case val1 > val2 than val1 or something else!I will have a look for an actual example maybe it is better to have one

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a subquery, you should put the condition *in* the subquery.  For instance, if you have:

```
(select sum(x) from . . . )
```

Then do:

```
(select (case when sum(x) > 0 then sum(x) else 0 end) from . . .
```

Comment: I am comparing values from two different tables: From one table I have to calculate a e.g. sum val1  and I have to compere the sum with a value from the second table val2. Depending on the condition would it be like case val1 > val2 than val1 or something else!

Comment: @xandi1987 . . . You example says `<big subquery>`.  I'm assuming these are the same, because they have the same name.  You can bring the `case` into the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite your query as

```
select 
   Column1,
   Column2,
   Case
       WHEN Column3 > 0 THEN Column3
       ELSE 0
   END
from 
(
    select 
        Column1,
        Column2,
        BigSubquery as Column3
    from ...
)
t
```

Then you avoid duplicating "BigSubquery", but you do duplicate the select list.

Comment: Ok but this is not really that I hoped to find! It seems that there is no construct which is offering that! Is it possible to declare a variable where I can hold the result of the subquery?

Comment: If BigSubquery is independent of the main query then you could execute it first and save the result in a variable.  Otherwise no.